# LinearLayoutManager smooth scroll jumps to wrong position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, smooth-scrolling, linearlayoutmanager

I'm am trying to make a layout similar to how Instagram's filter layout works. Basically when you select a filter it will scroll to the item you selected + 1 showing you that there are more filters.

I currently am trying to build a custom `LinearLayoutManager` for my horizontal `RecyclerView` here:

```
public class LinearLayoutSnapManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    private int mCurrentPos = 0;

    public LinearLayoutSnapManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public LinearLayoutSnapManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    public LinearLayoutSnapManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

    }


    public void snap(RecyclerView rv, int position) {
        if (mCurrentPos == position) {
            // No move
            return;
        }

        boolean goingRight = true;
        if (position < mCurrentPos) {
            goingRight = false;
        }
        mCurrentPos = position;
        smoothScrollToPosition(rv, new RecyclerView.State(), goingRight ? getScrollRightPos(): getScrollLeftPos());
    }

    private int getScrollLeftPos() {
        int newPos = mCurrentPos - 1;
        return (newPos > 0) ? newPos : 0;
    }

    private int getScrollRightPos() {
        return mCurrentPos + 1;
    }
}
```

Scrolling left works just as intended but when I'm scrolling right it seems to just jump to the end of the list versus the newItem + 1 and I can't figure out why it happens.

[image]

Comment: Could you post more of the code, I mean, how you are using those methods? Your logic seems to be fine, but you may be passing the position in the wrong moment, i.e.

Comment: It COULD be that when `getScrollRightPos` is called, an old (and not updated) position is being passed to mCurrentPos, so it scrolls to the OLD position + 1 (which may be at the end of the recyclerview).Also, it seems to me that you have a problem when you tap items that are not adjacent to current item, is the scroll working in those cases?

Comment: Who is calling `snap()`? Where `int position` is coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was calling my `snap` method in the interface callback from the `onclicklistener` in my horizontal list. Before the interface was getting called I was setting the selected item and then notifying the view had changed in order update the current state. This was causing all the issues with the layoutmanager returning the bad indexes.

I discovered this once I made an empty project and tested my logic. To my surprise with worked fine which allowed me to track down the real issue.

Once I moved the snaplogic before all my view logic everything worked as intended with no change to the code I posted.

Hope this can help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different solution. `LinearLayoutManager` comes with handy functions:

[`int findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition())

> Returns the adapter position of the first fully visible view.

---

[`int findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition())

> Returns the adapter position of the last fully visible view.

---

[`int findFirstVisibleItemPosition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findFirstVisibleItemPosition())

> Returns the adapter position of the first visible view.

---

[`int findFirstVisibleItemPosition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findFirstVisibleItemPosition())

> Returns the adapter position of the last visible view.

The first two function return the positions of fully visible views, whereas the last two return even partially visible views. The choice is up to you what behaviour you would like to achieve.

When using them, the functions `getScrollLeftPos` and `getScrollRightPos` should look like:

```
private int getScrollLeftPos() {
    int newPos = findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() - 1;
    return (newPos > 0) ? newPos : 0;
}

private int getScrollRightPos() {
    return findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()+ 1;
}
```

And don't invoke method:

```
smoothScrollToPosition(rv, new RecyclerView.State(), goingRight ? getScrollRightPos(): getScrollLeftPos());
```

from `LayoutManager`. If you have the reference to `RecyclerView`, invoke:

```
rv.smoothScrollToPosition(newPosition);
```

If you look into the source code of `RecyclerView` you will find such implementation:

```
public void smoothScrollToPosition(int position) {
    if (mLayoutFrozen) {
        return;
    }
    if (mLayout == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot smooth scroll without a LayoutManager set. " +
                "Call setLayoutManager with a non-null argument.");
        return;
    }
    mLayout.smoothScrollToPosition(this, mState, position);
}
```

This is basically the same as you do, but be aware that the function of `LayoutManager` is invoked with appropriate `RecyclerView.State`. It is just consistent with `RecyclerView`

Comment: So I think the heart of the issue is `findLastVisibleItemPosition()` doesn't seem to be right. When I click on the second item in the list it returns 0. Same with `findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()`. `Getchildcount()` is 1 when it looks there are 4 views attached to the recycler view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last selected filter is displayed secondly (one filter before, several filters after), you don't have the right approach.

In this case, regardless of direction Right or Left, the process is the same. The position of RecyclerView is always 1 less than the position of the selected filter, except for the first element.

(This example is not optimized for the latest position)

```
public class LinearLayoutSnapManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    private int mCurrentSelectedPos = 0;

    public LinearLayoutSnapManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public LinearLayoutSnapManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    public LinearLayoutSnapManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

    }


    public void snap(RecyclerView rv, int selectedPosition) {
        if (mCurrentSelectedPos == selectedPosition) {
            // No move
            return;
        }

        mCurrentSelectedPos = selectedPosition;

        int newDisplayPos;
        if (mCurrentSelectedPos > 0) {
            newDisplayPos = mCurrentSelectedPos - 1;
        } else {
            newDisplayPos = 0;
        }

        smoothScrollToPosition(rv, new RecyclerView.State(), newDisplayPos);
    }

}
```

Comment: This code has the same issue as above except instead of the jump happening when scrolling right nothing happens. When scrolling right I need it to behave how it does when scrolling left.

Answer (score 0):

this is because the 'position' which is being entered is not layout position , first find layout position like below and than apply smoothscrolltoposition.

```
  Common.foodlistnuber = viewHolder.getLayoutPosition(); //position
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
  recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(Common.foodlistnuber);
        }
    }, 200);
```